# Node.js - express hello world example error

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I try to learn node.js, and I want to use express framework for it, but when i copy and paste hello world example from expressjs.com page, it shows error:

```
/home/tomek/dev/node/express_server.js:1
uire, module, __filename, __dirname) { var app = require('express').createServ
                                                                    ^
TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/tomek/dev/node/express_server.js:1:92)
    at Module._compile (module.js:449:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:467:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:349:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:305:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:490:10)
    at startup (node.js:124:16)
    at node.js:807:3
```

I've installed express through npm and it looks ok. Its in `node_modules` folder in app's root directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

createServer is depracated. I dont know if server will not run, or just ping You with a warning, but we cant tell anything, as You didnt paste Your code.

If You use express 4, You can create server instance:

```
var express = require('express'),
    app = express();
```

instead of createServer.

here is official guide for express: http://expressjs.com/guide.html

You can also check for ie this link:
http://scotch.io/tutorials/javascript/build-a-restful-api-using-node-and-express-4
guide for whole restful api tutorial as good example of creating server with some routing in new express (lot of tutorials are outdated).

Comment: It worked but when I run the app I get TypeError: Cannot read property 'handle' of undefined

Comment: Someone actually solved it for me here: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23457434/node-js-express-socket-io-app-connection-error/)